# want to disable my next button until my all option are filled using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 6 dropdowns and next button and previous button.
i need to disable the next button until my 6 dropdowns are filled.
after filled all 6 drop drowns the "next" button wants to enable..

below code is the dropdown code:

```
                        <div class="q_category_details_right">
                            <img class="question_arrow1" src="left_arrow.png" id="firstpointer"/>
                            <div class="q_cell select_boxes margin_bottom_20">
                                <select onchange="currentChange(${jvar_question_number*2 +1}, this)" id="current${jvar_question_number*2 +1}">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="N">N</option>
                                    </select>

                                <img src="command_active.png" width="10" class="comment" id="imgCurrent${jvar_question_number*2 +1}" onclick="popup(this)"/>

                            </div>                  
                            <div class="q_cell select_boxes">
                               <select id="target${jvar_question_number*2 +1}" disabled="true">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="N" class="hide">N</option>
                                    </select>

                                <img src="comment_icon.png" width="10" class="comment" id="imgTarget${jvar_question_number*2 +1}" onclick="popup(this)"/>

                            </div>
                            <div class="q_cell select_boxes">
                                <select id="importance${jvar_question_number*2 +1}" disabled="true">
                                       <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="N" class="hide">N</option>
                                </select>
                                <img src="comment_icon.png" width="10" class="comment" id="imgImportance${jvar_question_number*2 +1}" onclick="popup(this)"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <j:if test="${questionsDB.next()}">
                    <div class="questions_content questionlist2" onClick="changeInstruct(2)">
                         <div class="q_category_details_left margin_bottom_20">
                                <div class="display_table padding_left_20">
                                    <div class="left_float">
                                        <p> ${jvar_question_number*2 +2}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="right_float">
                                        <p>
                                           ${questionsDB.assessment_questions}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="q_category_details_right">
                            <img style="display:none;" src="left_arrow.png" id="secondpointer" class="question_arrow2"/>
                            <div class="q_cell select_boxes margin_bottom_20">
                              <select onchange="currentChange(${jvar_question_number*2 +2}, this)" id="current${jvar_question_number*2 +2}">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="N">N</option>
                                    </select>
                                <img src="command_active.png" width="10" class="comment" id="imgCurrent${jvar_question_number*2 +2}" onclick="popup(this)"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="q_cell select_boxes">
                               <select id="target${jvar_question_number*2 +2}" disabled="true">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="N" class="hide">N</option>
                                    </select>
                                <img src="comment_icon.png" width="10" class="comment" id="imgTarget${jvar_question_number*2 +2}" onclick="popup(this)"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="q_cell select_boxes">
                                <select id="importance${jvar_question_number*2 +2}" disabled="true">
                                       <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="N" class="hide">N</option>
                                </select>
                                <img src="comment_icon.png" width="10" class="comment" id="imgImportance${jvar_question_number*2 +2}" onclick="popup(this)"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

the button id is "next"

Comment: Please can you show what jquery code you have tried ?

Comment: you can use Jquery to do it ,it will be very easy . $('#**').hide() /show()

Comment: What have you tried? I'm thinking perhaps a delegated change handler (bound to the div that contains all the fields), which when any select is changed checks the value of them all and sets the disabled property of the button accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var isEmpty = false;
    $(select).each(function(){
           if(!$(this).val()) {
              isEmpty = true;
           }
    });
    isEmpty ? $('your button id').prop('disabled', true) : $('your button id').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a change event to the select box and keep checking if all of them have been selected (assuming selecting means `value != ""` )

```
//bind an change event
$( ".select_boxes select" ).change( function(){

   var allselectboxchecked = true;
   $( ".select_boxes select" ).each( function(){

      if ( $( this ).val() == "" )
      {
         allselectboxchecked = false;
      }

   } );   

   //if all select boxes are selected then enable your button
   if ( allselectboxchecked )
   {
    //enable the button
   }

} );
```